# Oracle APEX - is there a way to call javaScript from List entry

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have a list region displayed on my page. Right now I have each entry open a page in the application, but what I want is for it to call javascript. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is possible if you create the list with a dynamic plsql region.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a shot

Comment: is there a way to call a dynamic action from a PL/SQL dynamic region? How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Yes of course my friend, just use javascript to call a function inside your page

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare your function in page scope

[image]

2. Call the function with Javascript from your PLSQL

[image]

3. The result is

[image]

4. I hope this resolves your question, is not dynamic action but a normal javascript function is almost the same. Both of them have events and actions :)